# Incorrect data length when invoking Fast Fourier Transform in AForge

Tags: c#, fft, aforge

I'm working on a FFT (fast fourier transform) function in C#. 
I've found AForge library but when using it I keep getting the error message:

> Incorrect data length.

The data I'm putting in is a list of doubles and the size can vary, depending on the signal I'm sending in.

What to do about this?

This is what my function looks like so far

```
private void FastFoulierMethod(ISignal signal, List<IMarker> markers)
{
    AForge.Math.Complex[] complex = new AForge.Math.Complex[samples.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.Count-1; i++)
    {
         complex[i] = new AForge.Math.Complex(samples[i].GetTimeInSec(),0);
    }
    AForge.Math.Complex[] complex2 = complex;
    FourierTransform.DFT(complex, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
    FourierTransform.FFT(complex2, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
}
```

Comment: Where does "samples" array come from ?

Comment: Welcome. First [no need to thank and write your name(we can see it in the right lower corner of post) in the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Second where you getting error? Third you probably missing last array item with `i < samples.Count -1`. `<=` maybe?

Comment: samples array is made earlier in the project, reading the csv file between specific time spans.

the last item in the array is always a zero value we don't use.

Answer (score 1):

As per [AForge documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e1932533-0745-940d-c998-140e8ee23927.htm):

> The method accepts data array of 2<sup>n</sup> size only, where n may vary in the [1, 14] range

So you would need to make sure the input size is correctly padded to a length that is a power of 2, and in the specified range:

```
double logLength    = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log((double)sample.Count, 2.0));
int    paddedLength = (int) Math.Pow(2.0, Math.Min(Math.Max(1.0, logLength), 14.0));
AForge.Math.Complex[] complex = new AForge.Math.Complex[paddedLength];

// copy all input samples
int i = 0;
for (; i < sample.Count; i++)
{
    complex[i] = new AForge.Math.Complex(samples[i].GetTimeInSec(),0);
}
// pad with zeros
for (; i < paddedLength; i++)
{
    complex[i] = new AForge.Math.Complex(0,0);
}
```

Comment: by using your code, the complex gets filled very strangely  have a look at this screenshot : http://imgur.com/y7i0zWj. with that i get a very strange fft graphic: http://imgur.com/EJYiyoV. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've left the data copy into `complex[i]` as you've set them (I've shown how to pad whatever data you want to take the FFT of). I can't tell whether the real part of the data does in fact correspond to your data (which I do not have), but the imaginary part appears to be approximately 0 (as per copied instance). The "FFT graphics" seems to show a graph of the input data (ie. pre-FFT), with axis being the real/imaginary component rather than the more usual magnitude vs. frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [AForge FourierTransform source code](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Math/FourierTransform.cs) you will find `ReorderData` method(at the bottom of file) which is called from FFT method. In this method there is check which rises error:

```
private static void ReorderData( Complex[] data )
{
    int len = data.Length;
    // check data length
    if ( ( len < minLength ) || ( len > maxLength ) || ( !Tools.IsPowerOf2( len ) ) )
        throw new ArgumentException( "Incorrect data length." );

    //rest of code...
 }
```

So the answer to your question is - **your array length must be power of 2 and be between 2 and 16384**.

Comment: thank you for your answer, we already thought of that. Problem is the array we put in isn't always the same length. Also, we can't just discard items out of our array to get a power of 2, so how should i fix this.

Comment: Probably you need to make bigger array which is of size 2^n, fill with your data and rest part of array fill with data not changing logic (0, 1 or other)